# Llamada a API web desde JavaScript

Tags: java, jquery, api, eclipse, google-chrome

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación web con Java, jQuery y Eclipse que realice peticiones a una API rest que devuelve valores climatológicos (openweathermap).

El problema es que no recibo respuesta cuando realizo la petición AJAX. En cambio, cuando copio la url a la que realizo la petición en el navegador, veo los datos en formato json.

Este es mi código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
    url: "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/uvi?lat=37.75&lon=-122.37&appid=27b59f3263c41d7194d722fec8cdcec2",
    success: function( data ) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("¡Ups! No puedo obtener información de la API");
    }
});
```

});

La consola del navegador me da el siguiente problema:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/uvi?lat=37.75&lon=-122.37&appid=27b59f3263c41d7194d722fec8cdcec2' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo hacer una petición a la API de OpenWeatherMap?

Agradecería mucho la ayuda, he intentado muchas soluciones posibles y no me funcionan.

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que poner la URL "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" delante de tu URL para que funcione.

Por ejemplo, en tu caso la llamada Ajax te quedaría así:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/uvi?lat=37.75&lon=-122.37&appid=27b59f3263c41d7194d722fec8cdcec2",
    success: function( data ) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("¡Ups! No puedo obtener información de la API");
    }
});
```

Comment: Porque debe colocar la URL especificada delante, es un requisito del API de `openweathermap` ? no queda claro lo que propones

Comment: Disculpa. Si, es un requisito indispensable de OpenWeatherMap. De otro modo, la api no funciona.

Comment: Excelente, es bueno agregar esa información y el enlace donde se indica, piensa que otras cientos de personas verán esto, o quizás miles...